# SPSite Object Problem When Trying To Loop Through Sites

Tags: powershell, spsite

I'm working in a Sharepoint 2007 environment. I'm trying to loop through a site, and it's subsites, and add a webpart to any pages found.

```
#Add SharePoint assemblies
[system.reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("microsoft.sharepoint")
[system.reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("microsoft.sharepoint.publishing")

#Get site and web objects
$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite(http://test.fake.com/en-us/testsite/)

#Walk through each Publishing Web and add the content editor webpart
foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) { #add webpart here }
```

My problem is that $site returns http://test.fake.com.. so when I hit my foreach loop it starts hitting anything under fake.com, and not /en-us/testsite/ and whatever sites below it. Is there something other than the SPSite object I should be using to accomplish what I want? Saying I'm new to this would be an understatement.. so bear with me.

Thanks for any help/insight.

Answer (score 2):

You can start from the SPWebApplication

```
[system.reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("microsoft.sharepoint")
[system.reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("microsoft.sharepoint.publishing") 

$wa = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication]::Lookup("http://test.fake.com")
foreach ($site in $wa.Sites) {
 foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) {
  #add webpart here 
  $web.Dispose()
 }
 $site.Dispose()
}
```

Comment: I didn't check to see if this would work for me because I ended up taking a slightly different approach. Part of my problem was not realizing only sites have .AllWebs, and webs only have .Webs. I'll post my solution as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing the below:

```
$site = new-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://fake.test.com")
$web = $site.OpenWeb("/en-us/testsite")
foreach ($subweb in $web.Webs)
{
 #do checking if publishing page / if checked out / add webpart / checkin and publish
 #dispose subweb
}
#dispose web && site
```

This allows me to target the site I was aiming for, and then go through all of the subwebs and add webparts to the pages within those. I did run into a problem checking a file in, which has me baffled as to why it's throwing an error, but I'll save that for another post & another day.

Comment: Is it preferred to use  new-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite in place of Get-spsite ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Get-SPSite](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff607950.aspx) instead of New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite(http://test.fake.com/en-us/testsite/)

Comment: It used Get-SPSite originally, but I was getting errors related to that...Saying that it isn't a recognized name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Someone told me that Get-SPSite is part of SP2010, but not SP2007 (which I'm using). [Not saying that's true, just what I was told.]

Comment: you should use `Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell` comand before, in other case you cannot work with sharepoint in powershell

Comment: Not to stray too far off topic, but I tried running that command, but it throws an error. I found steps to fix the error, but even those steps throw errors in the cmd prompt. I have another script that creates sites, subsites, and pages that works just fine, without using the PSSnapin command.

Comment: the powershell scripts runs in powershell.exe, not cmd.

Comment: Yeah, I'm running the scripts in Powershell. However, the 'how-to get ps snapin to work' sites I found required the use of the command prompt to navigate to a certain file in the .net folder. (InstallUtil.exe) and run that with a specified parameter. The parameters the sites gave were causing problems, however.